# Can all composite numbers be factored into a finite set of prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Can all composite numbers be factored into a finite set of prime numbers? For example, the set (2,3,5,7,11) can make up the the factors of an extraordinary amount of large numbers. Is there a maximum number of primes that exist to make up the product of all composite numbers?

Comment: No, a finite set of primes is never enough. In your example, consider $n=26$. The maximum number is "all prime numbers", so infinitely many. If one is missing, say $p$, consider the composite number $2p$, for example.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I don't come from a robust mathematics background.

Comment: Once again: suppose your maximal set is missing a prime $p$. How do you "make up" then the composite number $2p$ without having $p$ in your list? Take $p=13$ in your example.

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a finite set of primes that can be used as factors to construct all composite numbers?

Comment: @Théophile That is precisely what I mean. If yes/no, is there a theorem/proof?

It's just that through induction by testing random numbers, im finding that they almost always come down to being the product of a set of a repeating single digit primes.

Comment: It turns out to be no. I'll update my answer with an outline of the proof.

Comment: The question is ambigious : If you mean : "Can every given number be factored into a finite set of (not necessarily distinct) prime factors ?" , the answer is of course "yes". But if you ask whether a finite set of prime numbers is enough to build up all composites the answer is obviously "no" because we can muttiply arbitary many arbitary large primes together (with which we can guarantee that they are not in the given set)

Answer (score 0):

Every such maximal set $S$ must coincide with the set of primes $\Bbb P$.
To show this, suppose that your maximal set is missing a prime $p$ and consider the composite number $2p$.
Because of the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), we cannot factor $2p$ with different primes. This is a contradiction and we are done.

Comment: Does this allow for the elements of the set to be repeatable? For example, can all composite numbers be product of any number of the elements in a finite set, e.g. (2,3,5,7,11) or (2,2,2,3,7,7,11)?

Comment: Again: take your example, with $n=26$. Try to use $2,3,5,7,11$ and repeat them. Does it matter?